# function return an object

Tags: reactjs, arrays, function

I'm new in a react js and I want write a function that passed data as object(data is object {} )to get all q1 to q5 as price and p1 to p5 as vol finally I need to return new object ,this is my code here but don't return anything

```js
  const myfunction = ({ data }) => {
    const myData = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 5 + 1; i += 1) {
      const obj = {};
      obj.price = data['q' + i];
      obj.vol = data['p' + i];
      myData.push(obj);
    }
    return {
      name: 'ss',
      color: '#ffff',
      data: myData,
    };
  };
```

Comment: describe the problem

Comment: my code don't return any things, actually even don't read my function

Comment: show how you are calling the function and the data you are passing to it and log the result